Are there any FPS MMORPGs or MMO that are NOT select-target based? That you have to predict foe movement to aim and hit the target?
Are there any FPS MMORPGs or MMO that are NOT select-target based? That you have to predict foe movement to aim and hit the target?
The only one I know is NeoCron (but I cant stand the oudated low poly low res graphics), you need to aim and predict your enemy location to hit with slow projectiles, even with raycast instant projectiles it may be required.
All other MMORPGs that I know, you have to select a target and then "just" manage your skills and spells and your location (and to me that is utterly boring), but the target does not required to be aimed at, you dont have to predict their location.
So are there any other?
Can be FPS or 3rdPerson, the point is it being a shooter like, something you have to aim/predict to hit. You can shoot in 3rd person too.

I asked this in reddit but they did not allow asking for recomendations on that forum... (here the link with some comments: https://www.reddit.com/r/MMORPG/comments/1bsm9ub/what_are_the_fps_mmorpgs_that_are_not/)
but I got many answers there, and watched some videos, so I got these:

Planetside 2
Mortal online 2
Star Citizen
Darkfall

Feel free to edit this list just to simply add MMO names.
